# how to make smooth alpha animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a simple alpha Animation applied to a `TextView`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

<alpha
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toAlpha="0.1" />
```

After the animation ends, the alpha value jumps from 0.1 to its default value (1.0) again. How can I achieve that the `TextView` will fade in and out smoothly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is interested: I solved that by adding one more alpha item to the set (with opposite values). This results in a smooth fade in/fade out

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

<alpha
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toAlpha="0.2" />
<alpha
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.2"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

Comment: Tried this and still have stuttering animation.

Answer (score 3):

I know this answer occurs very late, but for those who are facing the same problem I want to share this simple solution:

```
android:repeatMode="reverse"
```

The reversion of your animation properties should result in a smooth fade animaton without a second alpha item.

Comment: Thanks for the post but it still does not smooth the animation, even with an 8KB image file.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is adding:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

and minimizing my app's background image's file size.